# How to get message id of sent message Bot Framework (Teams channel)?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, messageid

I am using Bot Framework SDK for Javascript. My bot is connected to the Teams channel. Right now I am saving every outgoing and incoming message from my bot to the DB.

But I want also to save reactions of user to my messages. That is why I am using `TeamsActivityHandler` and `onReactionsAdded` method ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=typescript#message-reaction-events)). In the docs there is written that `replyToId` field of `turnContext` is the id of message user is reacting to.

But when I am sending message to the user via `turnContext.sendActivity()` I don't know the internal id which will be given to this message on **Teams** side, that is why I can not pair reaction to the message stored in my db.

So my question is, How can I get the id of the message after sending it via `turnContext.sendActivity()` which will be later send in `replyToId` field to `onReactionsAdded` handler?

In other words I want to collect feedback (via reactions) on the messages my bot is sending to the user and save them to my DB (messages and reactions).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out (after some tries) that `turnContext.sendActivity()` returns `ResourceIdentifier` which contains one field `id` and that `id` is the id which will be given to the message on the Teams side.

EDIT:
For some ResourceIdentifier is empty when message sent to Teams is for example hero card. So this does not completly work.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the activity param after the await command to get this ID. So if we have our response in a variable reply (could be text, hero card etc...) we can get the ID after the await (inside the override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync method)

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);

string responseMsgId = reply.Id;
```