# How to get ResourceResponse.Id of a message being sent from Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I understand how to do this in code outside of composer, but is there a way to be able to use this within composer?

There's this: [How to get message id of sent message Bot Framework (Teams channel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328985/how-to-get-message-id-of-sent-message-bot-framework-teams-channel) but it's not from composer.

Comment: You'd have to use a custom runtime, is that a valid option for you?

Comment: I'm using it already, would the answer be creating a Custom Action that would send the response instead of doing it from the dialog file?

Comment: I'd probably do it in the bot itself, I'm posting an answer now.

Comment: You're right a custom action would be the appropriate place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd have to be in a custom action (as you mention) and then returning resource Id in the result property, so you can use it elsewhere. The `BeginDialogAsync` method of the custom action would something like this:

```cs
public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, object options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var activity = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();

    //...

    var resource = await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(activity);

    if (this.ResultProperty != null)
    {
        dc.State.SetValue(this.ResultProperty.GetValue(dc.State), result);
    }

    return await dc.EndDialogAsync(result: result, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the code use the "ResultProperty" property, just as the sample custom action in the custom runtime. This way the custom action would be much more reusable.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I'm also going to create an issue in git hub to see if they can make the SendResponse Action to do this as well

Comment: Hey, I guess you meant the `SendActivity` action but that comment poked my curiosity and took a peek at the source code and... guess what... [it IS already there](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/ececa515fc05c331d4ceeeca4b2b031fee39958c/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive/Actions/SendActivity.cs#L110), just have to check now how to use it 

Comment: I know it already exists in code, but I want to using it from Bot Framework composer. There's a SendResponse action in it, which internally would call SendActivity. But it doesn't return the value you see in C#.
Created this issue and the'll take it into consideration for future release: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/7850